# How do I Hook incoming messages from IM on iphone?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, hook, jailbreak

In regards to mobilesubstrate i was able to successfully hook Incoming SMS through the ChatKit Framwork /CKSMSService but this does not work when a message comes through as a iMessage.. Can anyone help me find the right framework and class that deals with incoming iMessages? I have hooked some IMCore classes but am unable to find a method that deals with the message just coming in...

Answer (score 1):

I would start by
   [looking here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=IMessage)

and also taking a look at [the CKMadridService.h header file](http://developer.limneos.net/index.php?framework=ChatKit.framework&header=CKMadridService.h).